# JQuery Attribute Toggle Workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using Javascript to try and toggle the source of an image on click, however so far am not experiencing expected behaviour.

```
$('.about-toggle').on('click', function() {
   if ($('.photo').is('src', 'image1.jpg')) {
       $('.photo').attr('src', 'image2.jpg')
   } 
   else {
       $('.photo').attr('src', 'image1.jpg')
   }
})
```

So far, on clicking the `.about-toggle` element, nothing changes to `.photo`. image1.jpg is in an image tag in the html, while image2.jpg is in my folder of assets.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/is describes and shows the expected usage of this method.

Comment: You'll want to check the docs for [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/).It doesn't work like you have it, though you could pass a function that makes the source check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$('.about-toggle').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.photo').attr('src') == 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cecece/fff') {
    $('.photo').attr('src', 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff')
  } else {
    $('.photo').attr('src', 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cecece/fff')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="photo" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cecece/fff" />
<button class="about-toggle">
  Click
</button>
```

Your code `if ($('.photo').is('src', 'image1.jpg'))` doesn't work as you expect,  [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) can't be used to check for an attribute value like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the old image `src` in a variable like:

```
var oldSrc = $('.photo').attr('src');
```

and then using ternary operator, toggle new image `src` like:

```
$('.about-toggle').on('click', function() {
  var oldSrc = $('.photo').attr('src');
  $('.photo').attr('src', oldSrc === 'image2.jpg' ? 'image1.jpg' : 'image2.jpg');
})
```

Or, simply using [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) syntax you can do this like:

```
$('.about-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.photo').attr('src', function(_, val) {
    return val === 'image2.jpg' ? 'image1.jpg' : 'image2.jpg';
  });
})
```